# How to use CSS to design a webpage banner with fixed image but editable text?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if what I want to achieve is even possible via HTML/CSS. If it is, please explain to me how to do it. If it isn't then please just say so.

I have a website in which at the top of each page, I insert a banner that I have created which has the page title in it. This is what the banner looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXXd.jpg)

Now normally I have to create a banner in Photoshop for each separate page and it is a bit time-consuming especially since there are so many pages. I was wondering if there was some way to use CSS styling so that I only need to upload the front part of the banner i.e. the crocodile head (this one: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1iTC.jpg))and then use CSS styling to create the black banner and the text that follows it. The banner:
1. Must have the exact same height as the neck of the croc.
2. The length should be able to be resized based on how long the text inside it is
3. Must have Arial Black fonts text in white color on top of it.

I'd greatly appreciate any help in this issue. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I had tried doing the CSS coding myself but it didn't work. I just didn't know that I had to post it here as well. This is what I tried first:

```
<div>
    <p><img src="Logo-Red.jpg"  height="53" style="float-left" />
    <p style="color:#FFF; font:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; background-color:#9e0000; margin-top:5x; height:30px; padding:5px;" >SPECIES
    </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

But that just put the logo and text on separate lines. So I tried this:

```
<div>
    <p style="color:#FFF; font:'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; background-color:#000; margin-top:5x; height:30px; padding:5px;"><img src="Logo-Red.jpg"  height="53" style="float-left" />
    >SPECIES
        </p>
</div>
```

But that didn't work either. The text did move up but was not aligned properly.

I didn't realize that people here were so rude. I thought this was a place where people could get help and learn. That's what it says on the front page in bold. I'm a newbie so if I made a mistake in my post, you can tell me how to correct it without being patronizing and discourteous.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but this is not a coding service. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is doable. And as other comments have suggested, you should first at least try before posting so that we can review your code and give advices.

What you want to set up would basically be a white `<div>` with a black `<div>` inside with margins up and down and a text box inside this black `<div>`.

Then you could use php to define a variable to be echoed on each and different page.

Hire someone to do it for you if you have no clue how to do it.